# Flex UI slow performance in Firefox/Chrome

Tags: flash, apache-flex, browser, adobe

The UI of my application is developed using AdobeFlex. I have only few text boxes and check boxes in it. My colleague is facing some problems in her system. When she tries to use the application on firefox or chrome she experiences very slow text loading effect. She says "it takes a couple seconds to catch up for each letter while typing". But when we tried it in Internet Explorer she feels better and the data also loads faster. Whereas I am not facing any problem of what she mentioned though we both are using the same OS(Windows 7). I do not face any issue like this neither in Firefox nor in Chrome(in my system) even though her system RAM is 2GB extra than in my system.

Can someone suggest a solution to this? A pointer/reference will also be helpful.

P.S.: I tried re-installing firefox and the flash plugin as well. Nothing worked.

Comment: Something related to frame rate?

Comment: No. When I type some thing in the text box, it has some delay in displaying it. I don't understand where frame rate is related to this.

Comment: Typing simple text should not have a slow down.  Does she experience problems with any other applications on the PC?  I wonder if their is a keylogger installed somehow on the slow system?  Or could it be a keyboard issue? Are you both on 64 bit systems?

Comment: @www.Flextras.com: we are in 32 bit machine. My RAM is 2GB and she has 4GB.

Comment: @Antoine Lassauzay: I believe there is nothing to do with code as  this issue is not reproducible at my end.

Comment: Well it could. Some part of the code might run very slow on her machine because of the CPU for instance, or something different with the environment.